# TomEE and Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-tomee, tomee-8

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.tomitribe.com/blog/its-easy-debugging-with-intellij-and-tomee/) but at the end I got an 404 Not Found.
http://localhost:8080/TomEE_war_exploded/

```
The requested resource [/TomEE_war_exploded/] is not available
```

In Intellij I don't see a mistake. The Apache Tomee runs under windows in ~/software/apache-tomee-plume-8.0.11 and the code in ~/playground/TomEE

[image]

[image]

Unfortuately I'm not able to understand how the war file will be copied to the ~/software/apache-tomee-plume-8.0.11/webapps directory or where the configuration error exists.

From the log file I'm not really sure that the deployment happend correct:

```
30-May-2022 16:49:53.486 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.batchee.container.services.ServicesManager.init You didn't specify org.apache.batchee.jmx.application and JMX is already registered, skipping
30-May-2022 16:49:53.486 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication Deployed Application(path=/home/maggus/playground/TomEE/target/TomEE-1.0-SNAPSHOT)
30-May-2022 16:49:53.664 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[2022-05-30 04:49:53,804] Artifact TomEE:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2022-05-30 04:49:53,804] Artifact TomEE:war exploded: Deploy took 823 milliseconds
```

Does anybody see the mistake?

Thanks,
Markus

Answer (score 2):

I ran into somewhat similar problem today and after sometime I was able to figure it out that it does not deploy at the following ***Application Context*** that is configured under ***Deployment*** tab in ***Run/Debug Configurations***.

```
/TomEE_war_exploded
```

If you try to access http://localhost:8080/TomEE_war_exploded/, it gives 404.

Instead, (in my case) it is accessible at http://localhost:8080/TomEE-1.0-SNAPSHOT/

[image]

Where ***1.0-SNAPSHOT*** is the version number defined in pom.xml.

Now in order to find the exact path where it is deployed, you need to go to ***Tomcat Web Application Manager*** at the following address:

http://localhost:8080/manager/html

Replace ***8080*** with the port number on which TomEE is running on your machine.

Default user & password is ***tomee***.

[image]

Look under Path and you'll find it. Just click on it, it will be accessible.

I hope it helps.

---

**EDIT: The Workaround**

In order to define your own path, you need to update the path in the Artifact Output Directory. See the attached photo.

[image]